# Dynamically change the value in range in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to dynamically adjust the field price to getting items.

I have these documents:

```
{"id":"1", "price": 200 }
{"id":"2", "price": 260 }
{"id":"3", "price": 180 }
```

For example, the where query in mysql should look something like this:

```
...
WHERE (price-50) < 160
```

So, I get the result with this mysql query: `id: 1` and `id: 3`

Is it possible to do in elasticsearch?

I come from the mysql database and I'm the beginner in elasticsearch, thanks.

Comment: why not simply send `price < 210` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-script-query.html) to build your search.

Here an example with `price`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['price'].value - 50 < 160",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```